# Problems with throwing exception

Tags: java

the method `public static List<Signal> fromString(String inps)` create and returns the `List of Signal` values found in the input string. If any characters other than those in `"01xX \t"`(including `'whitespace'`) are found, I must raise an `ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal` value. When I pass `1 x \tX 00` as input it throws an Exception when it should not. What's wrong with the logic of the code? Thanks in advance!NOTE:HI,LO,X are enum objects.

```
public static List <Signal> fromString(String inps)
    {
        List<Signal> values = new ArrayList<Signal>();
        for(int i = 0; i < inps.length(); i++)
        {
            if(inps.charAt(i) == '1')
                values.add(HI);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == '0')
                values.add(LO);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == 'X')
                values.add(X);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == 'x')
                values.add(X);
            else if (inps.charAt(i) != ' ' || inps.charAt(i) != '\t')
                throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(inps.charAt(i), "Invalid character!");




        }
        return values;

    }
```

Comment: because it is ALLWAYS unequal to a whitespace OR a tabulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this condition:

```
if (inps.charAt(i) != ' ' || inps.charAt(i) != '\t')
```

That will pass if the character isn't space *or* if it isn't tab. A single character can't be both space *and* tab, so at least *one* of the subconditions will be true. You want `&&` - although I'd extract the call to `charAt`:

```
char c = inps.charAt(i);
if (...)
...
else if (c != ' ' && c != '\t')
```

... or I'd just use a `switch` statement, which will be clearer IMO:

```
switch (inps.charAt(i)) {
    case '1':
        values.add(HI);
        break;
    case '0':
        values.add(LO);
        break;
    case 'x':
    case 'X':
        values.add(X);
        break;
    case ' ':
    case '\t':
        break;
    default:
        throw ...;
}
```